# Cucumber tests pass without functionality existing

Tags: node.js, testing, selenium, meteor, cucumber

I have started building a test suite for a Meteor app with Cucumber (following http://joshowens.me/cucumber-js-and-meteor-the-why-and-how-of-it/). Some tests are passing without any functionality in place.

For example, the test file `login.feature` includes `Feature: Allow users to login`, with `Scenario: A user can login with valid information` and `When I click on sign in link`

which is supported in the file `loginSteps.js` with:

```
this.When(/^I click on sign in link$/, function (callback) {
    helper.world.browser.
        waitForExist('.at-signup', 7000).
        waitForVisible('.at-signup').
        click('.at-signup').
        call(callback);
});
```

The sign in button actually has `class="btn btn-default navbar-btn"` and yet Velocity says that the test passes in 858ms. Another test passes `url(helper.world.cucumber.mirror.rootUrl + "event/1")` although there is no such url.

Other tests do fail, however, like:

```
getText('.user-menu .dropdown-top-level', function (err, username) {
            assert.equal(username[0], 'userme');
        }).
```

with error:

```
Then I should be logged in  Fail
 TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Honestly, helping you fix the actual error is hard without seeing the fixtures or whatever is inserting your users. Login stuff is actually tricky with Cucumber at the moment because the browser holds on to the cookie after you login. You have to forcibly logout at the end of your tests or at the start of your next test.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing a console.log(err) inside your getText statement. My guess is that you aren't finding a match when you run it.

Try something like this:

```
getText('.user-menu .dropdown-top-level', function (err, username) {
  if (err) {
    callback.fail(err.message);
  }
  assert.equal(username[0], 'userme');
}).
```

Comment: It shouldn't even get to this test, I think, because the test before this shouldn't pass but does. The problem I'm having is that the test that runs before this, i.e. the "click on sign-in link" test, is passing despite the sign in button having an incorrect class. In fact, it passes when I remove the button completely. So tests are passing when they shouldn't.

Comment: When I started adding error logging (and paying closer attention to the console) I saw more errors appearing. The stack shows that cucumber is reporting tests passing which the console reports errors on. e.g. test is: `click('.at-signup').` Velocity shows (in green): `When I click on sign in link 9390 ms` Console logs: `? (STDERR) Unable to find element with css selector '.at-signup'`. Not particularly enlightening, not sure what to do!